# Python NLTK Medical Entity Extraction

Tags: python, nltk

I am learning NLTK and I was able to write a program which performs entity extraction via (sent_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk).

However it is extracting entities related to all english words.

is there any tool/library on top of NLTK which can make it extract only medicial terms/entities?

Comment: You can use the nltk itself, but you'll need to find a corpus that annotates the medical terms, and use it to train your own chunker.

Comment: And had anyone built a corpus ... for nltk?

Comment: Find a corpus and you can sic the nltk on it. This you can get help with here, but "shopping" questions are off-topic as a matter of principle.